# ActiveRecord has_many :through association through multiple sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, has-many-through

I have a self referencing `has_many :through` model that has another has_and_belongs_to_many with another model. Basically something like this:

```
class Foo << ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :bars
  has_many :foo_links
  has_many :foo_parents, :through => :foo_links, :foreign_key => :foo_parent_id, :class_name => "Foo"
  has_many :foo_children, :through => :foo_links, :foreign_key => :foo_child_id, :class_name => "Foo"
end
```

I'd like to be able to have a `foo_child` item be able to belong to any `bars` to which it is assigned, as well as any `bars` to which one of its `foo_ancestors` (`foo_parents` and their `foo_parents`, etc) is assigned.  I was basically hoping to put together something like this:

```
has_many :inherited_bars, :through => :foo_parents, :source => [:bars, :inherited_bars]
```

I've never seen such an example, but I was wondering if it is possible to have an association that is a merger of associations from a through association.

Answer (score 0):

I think has_many association always tied to have an id somewhere to indicate the relationship, and allows you to modify this. Eg. you can add a new element to a has_many array, and the result is persisted back to the database. If you can merge two sources together, you lose the ability to link the rows by this.

A possible approach is this, readonly way:

```
has_many :a
has_many :b

def sum
  a + b
end
```